# Syntax help: The result of a sum (sumifs) in Excel is not correct

Tags: excel, sum, sumifs

Hi I am having trouble with getting the syntax right on a sum (sumifs) in excel.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($N$3:$N$1048576,$M$3:$M$1048576,{"Initial Contract","Up Sell"},$G$3:$G$1048576,{"North America","South America","Central America"}))
```

I've attached an example of the 3 columns that I am trying to sum, but the total is not summing correctly. Can someone help me with the syntax?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuqSD.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not retyping your data (that would have easily pasted into your question) but you have two condition in one criteria and three in another. Even with two-and-two or three-and-three this won't work properly because the conditions will pair up. You need to [TRANSPOSE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) one set of conditions.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($N$3:$N$1048576, 
            $M$3:$M$1048576, TRANSPOSE({"Initial Contract","Up Sell"}),
            $G$3:$G$1048576,{"North America","South America","Central America"}))
```

[image: Sumifs_Transpose_multiple]

Comment: Instead of using Transpose, couldn't one use `;` instead of `,` in one of the arrays?

Comment: That's an interesting approach Scott. I might look into that when I feel like dummying up some sample data.

Comment: I was unaware that by changing one to a horizontal array and the other to a vertical would make this work, so I learnt my one thing today.  I think I may go home and take a nap.

Comment: Scott, your method of applying a `;` instead of a using the TRANSPOSE function does indeed produce identical results.